# Can we take the suggestion from inlineSuggestion API to a different position in vscode extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

in the default behavior of inlineSuggestion API, by pressing TAB key, the suggestion will be added right after the cursor position. I would like to ask if it is possible to add the suggestion to some other places, after pressing the TAB key.

For example, say the cursor now is after apple, e.g. "apple|", and the suggestion is string "@", instead of "apple@|", is it possible to accept it as "appl@|e", where "|" just shows where the cursor is?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Basically I want to have control over the position where to insert the suggestion.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.